# Insertion failure "OperationalError: no such column"

Tags: python, python-3.x, sqlite

I tried to create a database with the names and phones I tried to fix but it replays to me any time:

```
File "exm0.py", line 14, in <module>
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Employee VALUES({0}, {1})""".format(k, v))
sqlite3.OperationalError: no such column: dani
```

Code:

```
from user_names import *
import sqlite3

# user_names.py
names = ["dani", "eric", "dinna", "tamir", "edan", "daniel", "tomer", 
"noa", "shalev", "tom", "shir"]
phones = ["0432", "5415166255", "61467254", "6146758", "5889482"]

connection = sqlite3.connect("")
cursor = connection.cursor()


cursor.execute("""CREATE TABLE Employee(Name text, Phone int)""")
acc = {}

for k, v in zip(names, phones):
    #acc[k] = v
    cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO Employee VALUES({0}, 
{1})""".format(k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

Don't do string formatting, use a prepared statement with placeholders.

```
for k, v in zip(names, phones):
    #acc[k] = v
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(?, ?)", (k, v))
```

You don't even need the loop, you can use the `executemany` method to iterate:

```
cursor.executemany("INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(?, ?)", zip(names, phones))
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not familiar with the style of prepared statement you are using.  In addition, best practice is to *always* specify the column names targeted for the insert.  Try this version:

```
for k, v in zip(names, phones):
    #acc[k] = v
    cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Employee (Name, Phone) VALUES(?,?)", (k, v))
```

Answer (score 0):

You're formatting the values into the statement's text without quoting them. The database thus interprets them as column names, and thus fails with the error you're seeing. Instead, you could just pass an array of parameters as the second argument of the `execute` function and let the driver library do the heavy lifting for you:

```
cursor.execute("INSERT INTO Employee VALUES(?, ?)", [k, v])
```