# How to insert a list of lists into a database table without "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "0": syntax error"

Tags: python, sqlite

I have a list of paths. Every path ends with a specific and unique numeric code before the extension of the file. "dir/12345.png".
I have also a list of lists in which every list has, in position 0, almost always, one of the specific numeric code of the paths, and in the other 3 index some values.

IF the value in position 0 of every element in LoL is equal the end of the path[n], I want to insert into a database a primary key, the path[n], string[x],string[z],string[y].

```
paths=[ "dir/subdir1/123.png", "dir/subdir2/456.png", "dir/subdir3/789.png"]
LoL= [ ["123", "string1", "string2", "string3], ["456","stringA", "stringB", "stringC"],["789", "stringQ", "stringW", "stringR"]]
```

I tried to execute the code bellow without any result and with this traceback:,

```
traceback:" cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO tableframe ({n},{paths[n]},{ele[1]},{ele[2]},{ele[3]})")
sqlite3.OperationalError: near "0": syntax error"
```

Code:

```
paths=[path1,path2,pathn]
lol=[[list1],[list2],[listn]]
connection= sqlite3.connect("Database.db")
cursor= connection.cursor()

tableframe="CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS frames (frame_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, valuex TEXT, valuey TEXT, valuez TEXT, valuew TEXT, valueq TEXT) "
cursor.execute(tableframe)
n=0
for ele in lol:
    if re.search(ele[0],paths[n]):
        print(f"{n},'{paths[n]}','{ele[0]}','{ele[1]}','{ele[2]}','{ele[3]}'")
        cursor.execute(f"INSERT INTO frames VALUES (f"{n},'{paths[n]}','{ele[0]}','{ele[1]}','{ele[2]}','{ele[3]}'")
        n += 1
        print('DONE')
```

What is the problem?

Comment: Don't use string formatting. Use a statement with parameters.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55781055/insertion-failure-operationalerror-no-such-column/55781075#55781075

Comment: It gives me now:  sqlite3.OperationalError: unrecognized token: ":"

Comment: Sounds like you have an extra `:` character somewhere in your SQL.

Comment: Show your code that's getting that error.

Comment: BTW, The problem with your current code is that you don't have quotes around the string values in the SQL.

Comment: E.g. `'{paths[n]}'`

Comment: I tried. And it gives me the same error. And If the problem is the ":" in the path ? Like "C: something/dir/subdir/file.png"

Comment: You got that error after you converted the code to use parameters instead of an f-string?

Comment: You're missing `VALUES` in the `INSERT` query.

Comment: .I added "Value" in the INSERT query and I deleted the "C:" in the paths, and now it gives me another error !!: "sqlite3.OperationalError: near "/": syntax error".
I am disperate

Comment: The contents of the pathname shouldn't matter at all if you're using parameters properly. Please show the updated code.

Comment: Thank you! I Checked in a better way the code" it was a problem of quotes !

Answer (score 0):

Don't use an f-string to substitute variables into the SQL, use a prepared statement with parameters.

Also, you left out the `VALUES` keyword before the list of values to be inserted.

```
for ele in lol:
    if re.search(ele[0],paths[n]):
        print(f"{n},{paths[n]},{ele[0]},{ele[1]},{ele[2]},{ele[3]}")
        cursor.execute("INSERT INTO frames VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)", (n, paths[n], ele[1], ele[2], ele[3]))
        n += 1
connection.commit()
```